# Unable to Update and delete in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, updates

I'm new in CodeIgniter, just watched the tutorial on youtube and followed the steps. 
I can't edit or delete records of my database. I can insert or fetch records, but update and delete functions always return error. Here is my code

Controller:

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Danhmuc_model');
}

function xoadm()
{
   $id = $this->uri->segment(5);
   $this->Danhmuc_model->delete($id);
   $this->session->set_flashdata('mess',' Đã xóa thành công');
   redirect(admin_url('danhmuc/xemdm'));
}

function suadm()
{
    $data = array();
    $id = $this->uri->segment(5);
    $row = $this->Danhmuc_model->get_info($id);
    if($this->input->post())
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('ten_dm',"Tên danh mục",'required');
        if($this->form_validation->run())
        {
            $tendm = $this->input->post('ten_dm');
            $input = array('ten_dm'=>$tendm);
            $this->Danhmuc_model->update($id,$input);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('mess',' Đã sửa thành công');
        }
    }
    $data['row'] = $row;    
    $data['temp'] = 'admin/danhmuc/suadm';
    $this->load->view('admin/index',$data);
}
```

Model:

```
function update($id, $data)
{
    if (!$id)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $where = array();
    $where[$this->key] = $id;
    $this->update_rule($where, $data);

    return TRUE;
}
/**
 * Xoa row tu id
 * $id : gia tri cua khoa chinh
 */
function delete($id)
{
    if (!$id)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    //neu la so
    if(is_numeric($id))
    {
        $where = array($this->key => $id);
    }else
    {
        //xoa nhieu row
        //$id = 1,2,3...
        $where = $this->key . " IN (".$id.") ";
    }
    $this->del_rule($where);

    return TRUE;
}
```

View:
Edit view:

```
<td>
    <input name="title" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['ten_dm'] ?>">
</td>
```

If I use this `value="<?php echo $row['ten_dm'] ?>"`, the text box doesn't appear the category's title (I'm inserting and editing categories)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1Ksq.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnmXl.jpg

But if I use this `value="<?php echo $row->ten_dm ?>"`, error with this message

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: danhmuc/suadm.php

Line Number: 13

I can't understand where is the error, please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean this http://codepad.org/pigH0vWb?

Comment: we need to see all the relevant `_rule` functions

Comment: `$id = $this->uri->segment(5);
    $row = $this->Danhmuc_model->get_info($id);` maybe the id is wrong. Show me the url

Comment: where clause missing before delete/update (unless you want to delete/update all records)

Comment: http://codepad.org/usOxjYhF. I have had $id variable on "$this->Danhmuc_model->update($id,$input);"